# Empty combobox values when access form loads vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to empty the combobox every time when form loads. Using the below code

```
   Private Sub Form_Load()

   combo1.RowSource = ""

   End Sub
```

But Combobax is not emptying.

Comment: A combobox has two parts: a textbox and a list. When you say empty the combobox, do you mean a) clear the textbox b) clear the list or c) both? Does `combo1` have a controlsource set?

Comment: My combo is not textbox.I want to clear the list. It doesn't have Controlsource set. But its Rowsource Type is Table/Query.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 6):

Your code is setting the rowsource of the combo box not the value.  The combo box can be cleared by setting the value directly.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

combo1 = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: No luck. My combobox RowsourceType=Table/Query,

Comment: Are you trying to set the dropdown list when you load the form?  My code will work best on an unbound combo box.  If you have the combo box bound to a field then we need more advanced code.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply . My combobox loads every time when button click, combo values comes from table columns. I want to empty combo every time when form loads.i.e before button click the combo should be empty.

Comment: I agree with @HelloW, that for an unbound combobox, just set it's rowsource to "". I just tested, and even if it is bound to a field, emptying the combobox rowsource will empty the combobox. Check ALL your code for refernces to the rowsource to see if some other code is setting it.

Comment: An addition to this: If your combobox is storing an integer or long integer (such as a key from an associated table) then you may want to set the `Combobox.Value = 0` instead of `""`. Otherwise logical tests such as `If Combobox.Value > 0` will incorrectly resolve as `True`.

Comment: combo1 = Null also works. Although "" will work, it could potentially cause a problem. In my case I had code that executed only if there was a value chosen in the combobox. By setting it to "" the code saw a blank string and therefore a value, so didn't execute. Setting it to Null instead solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend you clear using the following:

Me.comboBoxName.RowSource = ""

Me.comboBoxName = ""

Answer (score -2):

I used below and worked with me
me.combo2.value=""

Comment: Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.